# How to call a specific attribute from views?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have an application that tests if a value is greater than an attribute from my `ConfigurationForm`. If True, it sends an email to the e_mail attribute of my configuration form.

These are my views and my form files.
I don't know how to call the attribute?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from choix.forms import ConfigurationForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from choix.models import Configuration 
from django import forms 
from rasp import foo
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError


def index(request):
    x = Configuration.objects.temperature()
    to = Configuration.objects.e_mail()
    l = foo()
    subject = request.POST.get('subject', 'subject')
    message = request.POST.get('message', 'attention ! la temperature a depasse le maximum ')
    from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', '**********@gmail.com')
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i] > 14:
              if subject and message and from_email:
                  try:
                      send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [to])
                      return func(request)
                  except BadHeaderError:
                      return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                  return HttpResponseRedirect('mail')
              else:
                  return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
    return func(request)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from models import Configuration
from django.db import models


 class ConfigurationForm(forms.Form):
     e_mail = forms.EmailField(initial='********@gmail.com')
     temps = forms.IntegerField(initial='3000')
     temperature = forms.FloatField(initial='25.6')
```

Comment: `x = Configuration.objects.temperature()` cannot work as `.objects` is the model manager. Retrieve a `Configuration` instance via `c = Configuration.objects.get(**kwargs)` and access its temperature: `x = c.temperature`

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was really helpful :)

Comment: It worked but today I run my project it returns an error  .saying that configuration matching querry doesn't exist  I didn't edited anything it's the same code !!!!!